# Fundamental polygon $ba^{-1}a^{-1}b$

Tags: algebraic-topology

What surface does fundamental polygon $ba^{-1}a^{-1}b$ represents? I cannot find the corresponding surface, does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a diagram out of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, on page 51:

[image]

The right-hand space is the one you're after (relabelling), and it's homeomorphic to the one on the left via cutting and pasting. So you get a Klein bottle, i.e., $\mathbb{R}\text{P}^2 \# \mathbb{R}\text{P}^2$.